# How does socket.io behave when client attempts to set up websocket with older protocol?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am getting a javascript error 'Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header is missing' when attempting to connect to a socket.io websocket on older browsers (iPad 1 mobile safari, phantomjs). As far as I understand this is because these browsers are attempting to connect to a websocket using an older unsupported standard of the websocket protocol (phantomjs is sending a Sec-WebSocket-Key1 and Sec-WebSocket-Key2 with no Sec-WebSocket-Version as part of the handshake error).

When the websocket fails it should then attempt to connect via other transport methods (xhr,jsonp) however the socket.on('connect') never seems to fire for these transports after attempting to websocket handshake for an older protocol. The following is some debug output that we've added to our client.

```
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('connecting', function() {
    console.log('[Socket Client] Connecting to server using ' + socket.socket.transport.name + '(' + socket.socket.transport.sessid + ')');
});
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('[Socket Client] Connected to server');
});
socket.on('connect_failed', function() {
    console.log('[Socket Client] Connection failed');
});
socket.on('reconnecting', function() {
    console.log('[Socket Client] Reconnecting...');
});
socket.on('reconnect_failed', function() {
   console.log('[Socket Client] Reconnection failed');
});
socket.on('error', function() {
   console.log('[Socket Client] Error occurred');
});
```

When I connect via an older iPad or phantomjs I see the following in my console:

```
[Socket Client] Connecting to server using websocket(R1v2JlqiGbPDSL4R_LeS)
Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header is missing
[Socket Client] Connecting to server using xhr-polling(R1v2JlqiGbPDSL4R_LeS)
[Socket Client] Connecting to server using jsonp-polling(R1v2JlqiGbPDSL4R_LeS)
[Socket Client] Connection failed
```

This suggests that all transports failed but whilst watching through fiddler I see **multiple successful requests for both xhr and jsonp** firing after the connection failed. Note If I remove websockets from the list of transport types then xhr connects and socket.on('connects') fires as you would expect.

Should socket.on('connect') be getting called for other transports after the incompatible handshake with just one transport method being setup? Or is it expected that the developer has to configure socket.io when working with browsers with older websocket protocol (don't attempt to connect with websockets on those browsers)?

Thanks